# Is there a way to add an existing SQL Server database file to a project for integration tests?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, integration-testing

I can't seem to find the steps I need to do this process though Google\StackOverflow.

I have an existing SQL Server 2012 database installed locally on my localhost instance of SQL Server.

I would like to add the `.mdf/.ldf` files to a test project in Visual Studio and have a way for tests to connect to that database on machines other than my own. I believe the `.mdf` and `.ldf` need to be created when the project is built.

Comment: What I've been playing around with is having a **backup** (`.bak`) of a SQL Server database, and then in my test fixture setup (once per fixture), I just *restore* that backup onto my SQL Server instance using some SMO (Shared Management Objects) code. As long as your database is small enough, this is quite zippy (< 700ms in my case)

Comment: @marc_s - care to share you SMO snippets in a full-blown answer?

Answer (score 3):

**Hi maybe you can test it like this:**

1. Create your project.
2. Right click on you project Add > New Item… > Visual C# Items > Data > Service-based Database (.mdf and .ldf files will be created in your project)
3. Open mdf in server explorer.
4. Right click on .mdf inside server explorer and click "New Query".
5. In the "New Query" window you can paste a query generated for "schema and data" from sql-server.
6. Run the Query and you have all the schema and data from the original database.
7. There you can work as you like with the database as a localdb.

**For creating schema and data query in sql-server:**

1. Right click on your database in sql-server > Tasks >Generate Scripts.
2. Follow the wizard but on "Specify how scripts should be saved or published" option, go to Advanced> Types of data to script> Schema and data.
3. Save it on a file or save on clipboard.
4. Paste the entire query without the name of the database as in the point #6 in the above paragraph.

Hope it can help you.

Nelson Parra R.